# Cloud SQL crashed related to connections and threading issues, won't restart ("An unknown error occurred")

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

**Conclusion: Nevermind, GCP was down ROFL**

I have a MYSQL instance on cloud SQL and it has some read and write operations going on at all times, but neither the CPUs nor the memory is clogged or overloaded, I specifically checked.

It had been getting thread related issues for the past few weeks but this time it completely crashed and won't restart, every time I try and restart, it just says "An unknown error occurred"

These are the latest error logs from right before it crashed:

```
[Server] Can't create thread to handle new connection(errno= 11)"
```

and

```
[connection_h] Error log throttle:        742 'Can't create thread to handle new connection' error(s) suppressed"
```

Yesterday we moved the old data into a fresh new db and it was running well, but today it seems have been getting these thread related issues again and it crashed and won't restart.

Previously I tried to increase the `ulimit` by changing the `limits.conf` file but `ulimit` wasn't changing. Could that be the issue? Maybe a reconfiguration is needed?

BTW, `max_connections` flag is set to 10000, much higher than the default.

What can I do now? can't start the machine nor can I investigate. Feel free to ask anything.

Update:

1. I tried cloning the db but even clones are showing "unknown error"

Comment: is it working fine now? And you mentioned that GCP was down can you tell us where you found that?

Comment: It went up back again and then crashed again today, all on its own without us doing anything. Nothing on the error log except some new thread creation issues, we are completely confused and cant get to the bottom of it

Comment: Seems like your issue needs to be inspected at project level and in-depth analysis is required to check the route cause. I recommend to contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)